# Convert from String to Date from UTC format

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a date in a string format and I can't seem to be able to change it to a date format. I always get this error:

```
time data '14-08-16 22:22' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

The data comes from a CSV file and is in UTC format

Here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9GQf.jpg) from the csv file

[image]

and  the code I have done is this

```
test=pd.to_datetime(myframe['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 3):

`14-08-16 22:22` is not in the format of `%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S`

- `%Y` is the 4-digit year, `%y` is the year's last 2 digits
- 22:22 is only hour and minute,  `%H:%M`

The format should be `%d-%m-%y %H:%M`, see below example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
'04-12-16 20:43'
```